# Would it be appropriate to tell my neighbor's kids to quiet down when their parents are not at home?

Tags: relationships, conflict-aversion, conflicts, neighbors

For the past ten years, I have been living next door to a family with four kids and both of the parents work. They usually get home from work around 6:00pm on the weekdays.

Their four kids are latch-key kids who get home from school around 3:30pm each weekday. Whenever they come out to play in their back yard, they are always very loud, constantly screaming while playing and constantly teasing their 7 year old sister who is contantly screaming her head off. She has an extremely high-pitched scream and I swear you can hear this girl screaming from a half a mile away.

I have told their parents on multiple occasions that their kids make a lot of noise and all the screaming is unnerving, but I never seen their parents come out of their house to tell their kids to quiet down.

I have never told their kids to quiet down but this may soon be coming to an end because I just can't take it anymore.

Would it be appropriate for me to tell these kids to quiet down during the times when their parents are not at home?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes/no questions like "Can I"s are usually seen as off topic for the Inerpersonal stack as they tend to encourage poor answers.  I'd recommend editing your question to ask how you should go about talking to the kids or to their parents.

This question might also be a better fit for https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ .